# "Cannot verify access to path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot)", when adding a virtual directory

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to set up IIS web services and ASP.NET services on Windows Server 2008 R2. The physical directory was created, but I cannot get it to work. This is a fresh IIS Role installation.

[image]

The server is on a domain, and domain\server$ has read/write/browse access to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. Read/write/browse access is also granted to:

- Administrators
- Network Services
- Users
- IIS_IUSRS
- IUSR

**What I have tried so far**

- In the `Edit Virtual Directory -> Connect As` dialog, select Application User (pass through authentication). When I press Test Settings, I get the above error.
- In the `Edit Virtual Directory -> Connect As` dialog, select Specific user: `IUSR` (no password). When I press Test Settings, I get the following:
  [image]

**Other Notes**

Anonymous Authentication is Enabled, and Anonymous user identity is Application pool identity.

The Application pool configuration looks like this:
[image]

In the web browser, `http://localhost` returns an blank page but no error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They refer to embedded screen shots that immediately follow the text. "I get the following:" refers to the error, "Login failure: unknown user name or bad password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)."
"like this:" refers to the screen shot depicting the ASP.NET services.

Comment: I have the same problem using AWS and this AMI (ami-3aba0553): Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 English 64Bit SQL 2008 R2 SP1 Express. I followed this [QnA post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=98905&tstart=0) on their forum, and it did NOT work. Tried connecting locally; remotely via Windows Explorer; remotely via Firefox. Always gives: "**FTP Folder Error** Windows cannot access this folder. Make sure you typed the file name correctly and that you have permission to access this folder. Details: A connection with the server could not be established."

Comment: As indicated by the error, this is for an FTP web site.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I was having the same issue till just now; just as you mentioned, I tried "Connect As" and the username and password that I wrote down, was my machine's user (IIS is running on this machine), I tested the connection and it works now. Maybe if you weren't using that machine's user (try user with administrator privileges), you should give it a try, it worked for me, it may work in your case as well.

Comment: Thanks! I have a successful connection now:)

Comment: So strange. My next question is 'Why did this suddenly quit working?' -- I updated Perforce, and IIS quit working, and this fixes it? Soooo weeeeird.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure it out for almost a day.  I added IUSR and NetworkService to the folder permissions, I made sure it was running as NetworkService.  I tried impersonation and even running as administrator (DO NOT DO THIS). Then someone recommended that I try running the page from inside the Windows 2008 R2 server and it pointed me to the Handler Mappings, which were all disabled.

I got it to work with this:

- Open the Feature View of your website.
- Go to Handler Mappings.
- Find the path for .cshtml
- Right Click and Click Edit Feature Permissions
- Select Execute
- Hit OK.

Now try refreshing your website.

Comment: What if there is no handler mapping for cshtml?

Comment: Exactly, I can't find any *.cshtml in my case

Comment: Are you able to add a Handler mapping per these instructions? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753249(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by installing the development related features of IIS.

By default, IIS doesn't install all the required features.

You should install the IIS development related features to fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to go back to the internet information services, right clink on the intranet you created and select edit permission.

When the wwwroot pop up windows open, select the sharing tab and click "share" on the drop down menu select the users and their permission level or just select everyone and for permission read and Right

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Connect as" and select "specific user", then type in the credentials of your user (I used the admin of the server).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I hadn't installed ASP.NET through Server Roles and Features. Added that and it all worked as expected

Comment: Same for me, but it needed to be enabled in "Windows Features" on Windows 10. The checkbox is Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > ASP.NET 4.7. (Only ASP.NET 3.5 was checked initially.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the solution was uncheck the "use ports 80 and 443" on skype advanced configuration!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this problem can be found here:
[IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8/36597241#36597241)
This a good workaround but it does not work when you access the webserver over the Internet.

Comment: please don't just post a link, but give a sufficient answer to the question

Answer (score -1):

**ACCESSING LOCAL WEBSITE WITH IIS without Physical Path Authentication**

1. Make sure you have installed URL Rewrite to your IIS Manager

[image]

2. Open the URL Rewrite application then navigate to Inbound Rules>Import Rules

[image]

3. To import the rule, click the browse button then locate your .htaccess file then click import button

[image]

4. The text labeled with red are errors that are not accepted by IIS, so you have to remove them by clicking the errors in the converted rules and remove the text from the rewrite rules. Once you have get rid of the errors Click the APPLY button located at the top right corner. Then try to access your site without engaging users into the pool auth.

[image]

I hope it helps. That's what I did.

Comment: This (very detailed) answer doesn't have anything to do with the question at hand. Were you trying to answer a different question?