# FileUpload control does not save file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file and cannot get it to work. I have the correct url for the site and sub-folder. I have tried `fileUploader.FileName` and `fileUploader.SaveAs` as well. None seem to work. It is not in an `UpdatePanel`. Any ideas?

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub uploader_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
 If fileUploader.HasFile Then
    Dim _path As String = Path.Combine("{path to site and folder}", Server.HtmlEncode(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName))
    Try
      fileUploader.PostedFile.SaveAs(_path)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Response.Write(ex.ToString)
    End Try
 Else
  Response.Write("No File")
 End If
End Sub
```

New code, I need to get parent folder to expose the sub folder:

```
  Dim filePath = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName)
  Dim _path As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "subfolder", filePath)
```

`_path` = `\\{server blah}\{site}\webroot`

Now no error, but no file uploaded either???

Comment: Define not working? Exception? No PostedFile?

Comment: It does not print anything to the `Reponse.Write`, it does not save file.

Comment: Can u put a breakpoint at the `IF` and follow it step-by-step to see what is happening?

Comment: If I test it on localhost all works well with local folders.

Comment: If its working fine on the local host and not working when hosted, then the most probable reason would be file permissions. Also right click the page to view source after submitting the file. You may not see the error written by response.write since the page conatins a lot of html and all.

Comment: I am now getting an error `Could not find a part of the path '\\{server blah}\{site}\{subfolder\{filename}'.` and this looks just like the path should be - what gives?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set File Permissions if you are on Hosting provider. If you are using a shared hosting, then there would be options to do it. If you have access to IIS, then you can do it yourself.

Comment: I bet not, I will look into it.

Comment: I do have access to IIS, what do I need to do?

Comment: If you are sure, this is n't the problem, then turn off custom error mode in web config and see the error if any.

Comment: I enabled this folder in the Directory Browser - it was disabled. No change after doing this though.

Comment: Do `fileUploader.HasFile `?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last comment. I don't know how to debug a published site. The localhost works fine.

Comment: How do I check if it is `ReadOnly`?

Comment: For which user did you give permission? you have to give permission to IIS users. Giving permission to any other user won't make any sense. Also try giving permission to all users.

Comment: I don't understand how to set file permissions, sorry new to IIS stuff.

Comment: Do you mean on the file itself?

Comment: If you trying to access a file, then file. There won't be any error because your code is safe inside try catch block. remove that try catch and see the error. The error will take you to the right direction. If the site is hosted and not  private give the link, I can check it .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8

Comment: You have to set permission to IIS IUSERS .. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-setting-folder-permissions-6-of-12

Comment: In `IIS` the `.Net Roles` have been disabled, and the `.Net Users` has an error and does not load.

Comment: I am now getting an error `Could not find a part of the path '\\{server blah}\{site}\{subfolder\{filename}'.` and this looks just like the path should be - what gives?

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath("subfolder")`. I hope The the subfolder is virtual path. ie. www.yourdomain.com/subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Modify your third line like this

```
Dim _path As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("{Relative url of your folder within your project}"), Server.HtmlEncode(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName))
```

Relative URL should be something like this:

```
"~/folder/Folder2//"
```

---

Comment: `The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path`

Comment: I am now getting an error `Could not find a part of the path '\\{server blah}\{site}\{subfolder\{filename}'.` and this looks just like the path should be - what gives?

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked, must be delay between publish and using the new files - cloud based. It is working as expected wit this path.

```
If fileUploader.HasFile Then
  Dim filePath = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName)
  Dim _path As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~")).FullName, "subfolder", filePath)
  Try
    fileUploader.PostedFile.SaveAs(_path)
  Catch ex As Exception
    lb.Text = ex.Message
  End Try
Else
  lb.Text = "No File!"
End If
```

Thanks for the help everyone.