# IIS or IIS_IUSRS permisions so that PHP can write files for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, permissions, iis-8

I'm running IIS 8 on a virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 Datacenter) in Azure. I have [installed WordPress](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/wordpress.aspx) and its dependencies using the Web Platform Installer 4.6

I have trouble when WordPress needs to write files from its admin console. I've added the ftp details to the file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\wp-config.php` and that works fine. But whenever WordPress tries to write a file from its management web page, for example to create a child theme or to upload media I got an error (e.g. 'failed to upload due to an error' or 'Target child theme directory cannot be created. This is probably a permission error'.)

I can fix this using [EvilDr's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14934006/575530) of adding permissions to the IUSR account. But I am nervous about this since it seems that [IUSR and  should *only* have access to precisely what it needs; it should never be given access to anything else](https://serverfault.com/a/50132/203196).

Is giving IUSR read Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, and Write permissions for the WordPress directory `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog` and its subfolders the correct and safest way to get WordPress working on IIS 8?

Answer (score 0):

Giving `NETWORK SERVICE` write permission to the folders that WordPress needs to write to should do the trick.

UPDATE: `NETWORK SERVICE` will also need Read & execute, List folder contents and Read permissions.

EDIT:
Thought I'd add the file/folders etc.. for completeness:

```
/wp-config.php
/wp-content/       (recursively)
```

Comment: I get "Error saving media attachment" when I remove the IUSR permissions and replace them with the ones you suggest.

Comment: `NETWORK SERVICE` is one group. You also have to give Read & execute, List folder contents and Read to `NETWORK SERVICE`. Also just so we are clear. `IUSR` still needs to be there, just without Write access. Also make sure you apply the `NETWORK SERVICE` group recursively so all the sub folders have the permission...

Comment: Nope, giving Read & execute, List folder contents, and Read to IUSR recursively on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog and Full Control to NETWORK SERVICE recursively on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\wp-content and C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\wp-config.php gives me an "Error saving media attachment" when uploading media via the console

Comment: Check Where PHP's temp directory is set to, and add `NETWORK SERVICE` to that folder with the same permission as above. Use `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` to get the temp directory location...