# How to output a file to Desktop in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a problem output my log file to my Desktop. I am using Windows 7.

```
<?php 

        $log = "All the log file !";
        $file_name = 'data.txt';
        $file_path = 'Desktop\\test\\'.$file_name;
        file_put_contents($file_path, $log );
```

On my **Desktop** already have a **test** folder.

[image]

when I open it, nothing is there

[image]

What did I do wrong - here ?

Comment: Have you tried: `$file_path = ' C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\Test`?

Comment: Yeah, your desktop path isn't "Desktop", it's "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop"
Also, make sure the Test directory is writable.

Comment: Besides comments above, is PHP installed? Just checking ;-)

Comment: I'm not  Windows user, but shouldn't it be:  file_put_contents( 'C:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\test\\'.$file_name , $log );

Comment: I did do that - check out the update on my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you desktop folder is located at:

```
C:\Users\{username}\Desktop
```

Second you can try to check the result of the file_put_contents function.

Third, if you have any problem, first turn on the debug/test mode of your Framework, or if you are not using one just add this on top of your file:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

For easier:

```
$file_path = 'C:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\test\\'.$file_name;
```

Comment: I did `$file_path = 'C:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\test'.$file_name;`, still didn't see anything output !

Comment: Did you checked this path in Explorer?

Comment: @kula That code will create file on desktop not inside `test` this is correct `'C:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\test\\'.$file_name;`

Comment: This is exact path in Explorer = `C:\Users\bheng\Desktop\test` - and I see nothing there ! when I refresh the page !

Comment: Good move to turn on error reporting. It's always tough to tell with code fragments, but the missing ";" on the line: file_put_contents($file_path, $log ) may be a problem. @Bogdan Kuštan I can see you've corrected that.

Comment: @BigScar : Good called, I caught that as well, but that is not the problem here. I fixed that, and nothing generated.

Comment: @LachezarTodorov : I throw that 2 lines that you suggest on the top of my php file, and I don't any error showing. At the same time file is still not export .

Comment: @LachezarTodorov : Not I got sth different. `Warning: file_put_contents(C:\Users\bheng\Desktop\test\data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.php on line 7`

Comment: That line 7 is this line  = `file_put_contents( 'C:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\test\\data.txt', $log );`

Comment: Well that being said, do I need to adjust and permission level on my `test` folder ?

Comment: So you have to change the folder permissions.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://serverfault.com/questions/159902/change-permissions-in-window-7-so-php-can-write-files

Comment: Are you using wamp, other *amp or custom installation

Answer (score 0):

file path in windows to desktop is `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Desktop`. So You need to adjust path, or use $_SERVER['HOME'] variable if you are running from CLI.

```
$log = "All the log file !";
$file_name = 'data.txt';
$file_path = $_SERVER['HOME'] . '\\' . 'Desktop\\test\\'.$file_name;
file_put_contents($file_path, $log );
```

Or generate path to desktop:

```
echo exec('echo %SystemDrive%') . '\\Users\\' . get_current_user() . '\\Desktop\\Test';
```

Becauso You are using IIS, PHP runs as different user. Su You bus hardcode Your path:

```
$file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\Test\\' . $file_name;
```

Comment: are you using CLI? Bogdan wrote: "if you are running from CLI"

Comment: No - I didn't. I used IIS in wondows 7 to load/run/display my php code.

Comment: @Bogdan - you're right, now I got a different error message saying that `Warning: file_put_contents(C:\Users\bheng\Desktop\test\data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: How to do I fixed this issue ? Is there a way to force save it ?

Comment: @kula You need to set permissions to write to desktop folder. Firstly get username which PHP is running with `get_current_user()` and then in folder properties security tab, allow that user write permissions.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan : I did this `echo  get_current_user();` - and I got wired return `IUSR ` - I don't know who is IUSR !!!

Comment: @kula `IUSR` is Your IIS user as which PHP is running. You need to allow write permissions on Your `test` folder to `IUSR` user, more about permissions could be found [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot write directly to the user's file system.

what you need to do is use php to trigger the user to download the file you're trying to deliver.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: __Maybe__ he's trying to write in its own server/pc. BTW, I'm ironic, PHP is server side, so it's obvious he's doing what I've said :)

Comment: And in Windows 7 it's really easy to do this ... the file permissions there are not so strict.