# PHP - Creating Backup Path

Tags: php, mysql

I want Create MySQL Backup

this Code Working Perfect

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\Najva\Desktop\backup/';
if(!is_dir($folder))
mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
chmod($folder, 0777);

$backup_file_name =$folder. $database. "_". date( "d-m-Y--h-i-s"); // Create Backup File NAme
$handle = fopen($backup_file_name .'backup.sql', 'w+');

fwrite($handle, $return);
fclose($handle);
echo "success";
```

but  i really want like this

```
$pathfoder = $_POST['value'] ; // Same Link C:\Users\Najva\Desktop\backup/
$folder = $pathfolder;
if(!is_dir($folder))
mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
chmod($folder, 0777);

$backup_file_name =$folder. $database. "_". date( "d-m-Y--h-i-s"); // Create Backup File NAme
$handle = fopen($backup_file_name .'backup.sql', 'w+');

fwrite($handle, $return);
fclose($handle);
echo "success";
```

it showing error

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in C:\wamp\www\dbbackupmaster\new.php on line 61

Warning: chmod(): Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\dbbackupmaster\new.php on line 62

Comment: Possibly related: [How to output a file to Desktop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28502105/1022914)

Comment: typo - `$pathfoder` != `$pathfolder` . So very likely it's trying to use a path which is incomplete or doesn't exist

Comment: BTW, please don't directly create files on disk from whatever values someone sends to your server. You should at least verify the extension and make sure it's one of a list of accepted extensions.

Comment: Félix Gagnon-Grenier: How to create this.. Give for example