# IIS 8.5 Virtual User IIS Apppool\ApplicationName Denied Access to directories

Tags: iis, applicationpoolidentity

We have a conundrum, and I am at my wits end with this issue. It is the same issue as this [IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8) thread... except the fixes don't work. The only thing that I believe is different is that we are running IIS 8.5 and the other post is running IIS 8.0.

I have it working with a service account from AD, but I would rather use the built in virtual account as I understand it is more secure this way.

Checking effective access on the IIS Apppool\Mydomain it has the correct access. For some reason it seems that it is just not adding the permissions as [Effective Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetoU.jpg)

Clicking on Application Pools and then the domain then advanced we have ApplicationPoolIdentity under the [identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok2Vb.jpg)

ACL on the directory for MachineName\IUSRS has read only [ACL for IUSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWrlO.jpg)

ACL on directory for IIS Apppool\ApplicationPoolName [ACL for ApplicationPoolName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ItM.jpg)

Anything that could help is welcome. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: “I have it working with a service account from AD, but I would rather use the built in virtual account as I understand it is more secure this way.” That's incorrect. The built-in virtual account has advantages over common built-in accounts like Network Service, but no advantages over an AD service account.

Comment: Do you have Windows Authentication ? What is the error that the users see when accessing the site ?