# IIS server 7 php 5.3 can not access sub folders

Tags: php, css, iis

My website runs correctly on xampp server, but I tried the Windows PHP localhost server (IIS), but for unknow, reason mysite.php run but can not show the CSS or the image that are on subfolders

I tried to give full access permission but with not help, and I have no idea what else can I do to make my PHP website able to access the subfolder that contains CSS/images/and txt files.

Comment: Please make sure you did not create file name same as your asset folder. This can be a problem to load the assets directory/files.

Comment: I did not just checked it again anything else I can check or do ?

Comment: Make sure that the folders have IUSRS user added to them, with read/execute access.

Comment: Also, if this is a development environment, turn on full errors in IIS, so that you can get a more detailed report as to what's going wrong.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8 about permissioning with IIS.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly try to use browser's F12 develop tool's netwrok to check what happened when you load the css/images/txtfiles. It will show the error message when you click the css/images/txtfiles as this [images][https://i.stack.imgur.com/x68JD.png].