# IIS/IISnode - not serving files (no error messages)

Tags: iis, iisnode

I have a Node project running on a Windows server using IISNode on a Windows virtual machine.

Everything worked fine up until a few days ago when the VM underwent a Windows update, and now the site isn't serving any files.

When I start the server, there is no indication of anything being wrong, but when I go to the URL, I get the message:

> www.mydomain.com didn't send any data
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Initially, when I was checking all the settings, I noticed that when I clicked 'Test Settings' under basic settings, that there was an authorization failure saying it cannot verify access to the source code directory.

But when I changed it to connect as **specific user** instead of **application user**, the error went away but the above issue was unchanged.

This makes me think it *could* be a permissions issue, but I've granted permission to the App Pool, IIS_IUSRS and IUSR, so I could be wrong.

I've tried multiple solutions on StackOverflow, including [this highly rated one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8) with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly, I found the answer a few hours after placing the bounty.

The problem was that it didn't have a static IP address, so when the VM was updated it was on DHCP and so was allocated a new IP, hence the website stopped working.