# .Net Core on IIS8 CreateDirectory no permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to create a folder when I deploy my application and start it on my IIS8 but I am getting this error:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\ApplicationsFolder\CentralApplicationSettings\' is denied.

This is the code in my Startup.cs:

```
var centralApplicationSettingsDirectory = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(MSCASGlobals.CentralApplicationSettings));
```

When I deploy and start my application, the folder isn't created and when I try to start the application in my browser, I get the error above.

I have tried to give read/write permissions to my application pool identity already but it still doesn't work. What else am I missing?

Comment: What user is your application pool running as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried add permissions for IIS_USR?

Here is the link:
[IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)

Or

Add for Application Manifest File the following line

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

This cause your application will run with admin privileges and you can access c drive.

Comment: I added permissions for IWAM_FileSharing

Comment: The link you gave me is to a very specific folder. I want to be able to create a folder in the c drive

Comment: Why don't create manualy after that you can add permisson like in the link. Or is this necessary to create programatically?

Comment: its necessary to create it programatically. The thing is, if i create it in this link: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\stardocs-digital.my\dev.stardocs-digital.my, it works fine. I tried replicating the permissions but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Is this a security risk?

Comment: Yes, it is but unfortunately writing onto drive C with web application is a security risk too.