# The system cannot find the file specified in c# (no upload)

Tags: c#, file

this morning my application developed in C# ASP.NET has a problem that has never occurred before

this application stores the filename within the column of a database

when it comes time to send the attachment via email, the application looks for the file name and attaches it to the message

the application cannot find the attached files on the physical path of the server even if these files are correctly present and block sending an email with attachment

the error is

> The system cannot find the file specified 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\newfile.pdf'

the file `newfile.pdf` instead it is located inside the public folder

how to do resolve this?

my simplified code below

```
List<string> listofattachments = new List<string>();


using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listofattachments.Add(reader["attachment"].ToString());
        }
    }
}


foreach (string attachments in listofattachments)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachments))
   {
      mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\public\\" + attachments.Trim().ToString())); //line of error
   }
}
```

Comment: code doesn't break by itself. what have you changed since it last worked? meaning both code _and_ server configuration?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks for reply. nothing has changed in the code, in fact other users are able to send the email message... only one user reported this

Comment: Code is not the only variable here, how about permissions for the apppool to read the directory file ext. is it hidden...

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks, on the public folder i have setting everyone user write and read. the newfile.pdf was entered two days ago, but this morning when you try to invalidate the message it crashes with error

Comment: `Attachment(@"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\public\\" + attachments.Trim().ToString()` is really messy.  Instead you should use `Path.Combine` then follow that up with a `File.Exists` or better yet `FileInfo.Exists`.  Using  `string` for path manipulation is error prone

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, But "*everyone*" may not be enough for IIS (maybe someone could clarify that). You could try give your directory explicit permission , ISS AppPool\<your application pool>

Comment: The comment above by @TheGeneral poses some good points.  Again, I'm no expert but I did find [this interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597241/585968)

Comment: thank you all for suggestions, i have solved using `Path.Combine` and `FileInfo.Exists`

Comment: @"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\public\\" is wrong. It should either be @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\" or "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\public\\"