# Not able to run the command "wfastcgi-enable"

Tags: python, django, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, wfastcgi

So I am trying to deploy a python Django project on windows server 2012R2. But when trying to  run the command I get this error.
[image]

When trying to open the link in IIS manager it show `error 500`.
[image]

I am running command prompt as administrator but that did not solve the problem.

Python version:3.8.8
IIS 8
If you need to know version of any other library to answer please comment.

Comment: wfastcgi is deprecated by Microsoft, you should use Python on Linux if possible. or you can try to assign iusr and iis_user full permission for the python folder and site folder.

Comment: Cant run on python on windows as its an organization server. Could you elaborate on the second method.

Comment: find you python folder and site folder, follow this link to assign iusr and iis_user full permission to them: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597241/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597241/13336642).

Comment: It didn't work. I have looked through numerous links in the past week to solve this problem but no success.

Comment: You can also check the log on the python side, there should be detailed error messages.

Comment: Could you tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the wfastcgi-enable.exe in command prompt as system administrator
write "cmd" on windows start, then right click and run the command prompt as administrator. then go to the directory where your python environment install the fastcgi . then run the wfastcgi-enable.exe command
That is how I made it work.