# "Could not find file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\ReportRDLC\ADV_TR_Balance_Ver2_1.rdlc'?

Tags: c#

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone guide me on this?

> Could not find file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\ReportRDLC\ADV_TR_Balance_Ver2_1.rdlc'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

in C#

I tried by adding file in BIDS 2019

Answer (score 0):

Since the stack is giving a IO error, here's a few things you should check,

1. the file permission of 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\ReportRDLC\ADV_TR_Balance_Ver2_1.rdlc'

   This should be accessiable by `IIS_IUSRS`
2. the file is actually exist in the specified location
3. the account identity of the Application Pool that your site is running on should have sufficient permission to access `ADV_TR_Balance_Ver2_1.rdlc`, similar issue as `1.`

Comment: Can u please guide me for points 1st(this should be accessible by IIS_IUSRS) and 3rd

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597241/6670491 ,IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS